# No grub menu in dual boot with Windows 7

Tags: 12.10, boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10, and once I restarted and changed the boot order to normal, it just went like a normal boot into Windows 7. I couldn't even select which OS I wanted to boot into. So I tried booting with the Live USB, but came up with the install again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add the following information to your question: Do you have multiple harddrives? Do you use UEFI or BIOS? What do you mean by "came up with the install again", are you refering to windows 7? Which LiveUSB did you use?

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot on your Ubuntu disc (DVD or liveUSB)
2. Choose "`Try Ubuntu`"
3. Connect internet
4. Install and run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)'s `Recommended Repair`. If any issue, indicate the URL that will appear.

[image]